# function inside FOR LOOP execute only once

Tags: php

i have an array of email add that needs to be verified. When I call the function during iteration, loop stops after first iteration and does not proceed over entire array. and the return value.

$num contains 6, and $email compose of (1st@yahoo.com,2nd@yahoo.com,3rd@yahoo.com, 4th@yahoo.com, 
 5th@yahoo.com,6th@yahoo.com) the only valid and registered email are 1st@yahoo.com and 6th@yahoo.com, but im only getting the 6th@yahoo.com which is the last.

```
  function get_email_verification(){
        $num = count($this->get_payqucker_emails());
        $email = $this->get_payqucker_emails();
        if ($num){
            for($i=0; $i < $num; $i++){
                $api_request_url = "http://api.payquicker.com/api/IsActiveAccount";
                $param = "email=".$email[$i];
        $result_request =  $this->do_request($api_request_url, $param, 'GET', 'json');   
            }
        }
        else {
            echo "All payee emails are already registered to Payquicker";
        }
         return $result_request ; 

    }
```

The do_request function will pause a json/xml value to (GET/POST) in Payquicker APIs

Comment: Not a direct problem but the code would run sooooo smoother if you'd do $num = count($email). There is no need to call the function twice.

Comment: this only execute once $result_request =  $this->do_request($api_request_url, $param, 'GET', 'json');

Comment: @ArkNet How do you know code inside the loop executes only once?

Comment: @Konstantin becoz im only getting 1 return 1 email.

Comment: Can use please add do_request function definition?

Comment: you get 1 return value you overwriting it try, `$result_request[]`

Comment: @ArkNet Problem is in this assignment then `$result_request =  $this->do_request($api_request_url, $param, 'GET', 'json');`. Change it to `$result_request[] = ..`

Comment: @cske I use foreach as what you suggest and it gives me the correct answer

Comment: @Konstantin i thought for loop will do, bcoz its really working when you try to code it.

Comment: Can someone pls up my question so im not getting negative points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use foreach:

```
function get_email_verification(){
            $result_request = array();
            $api_request_url = "http://api.payquicker.com/api/IsActiveAccount";
            foreach ($this->get_payqucker_emails() as $email) {

                    $param = "email=".$email;
                    $result_request[] =  $this->do_request($api_request_url, $param, 'GET', 'json');
            }
            if (empty($result_request)) {
                echo "All payee emails are already registered to Payquicker";
            }
            return $result_request;     
     }
```

Comment: what difference will it make? (between for and foreach)

Comment: @cske Thank you im getting the two email.

Comment: Move `$api_request_url = ...` before foreach. Not clean!

Comment: @hallaji yes i move it above as that is constant var.

Comment: @itachi: array keys can be anything, php arrays naturally hashes